# Using javascript objects with UTF-16 property names

Tags: javascript, c++, ajax, utf-8, yajl

I'm calling a service that returns UTF-16 json data.
My question is if the JSON object has UTF-16 strings as property names is there a simple way to reference these properties?

For example, here is how the response data looks like after calling JSON.stringify on it:

```
"{"C\u0000o\u0000n\u0000t\u0000e\u0000n\u0000t\u0000s\u0000":{ ...
```

In my code I'd like to do something like `data['Contents']`. Is there a simple way around this that avoids either hardcoding the strings with unicode escape sequences?

Update: changed to indicate strings are UTF-16.

Here's an example (Visual C++) of the call to generate the JSON output:

```
wchar_t* str = _T("Contents");
yajl_gen_string(g, (unsigned char*)str, wcslen(str) * sizeof(TCHAR));
```

Comment: That looks like UTF-16 LE, not UTF-8...

Comment: It actually looks like UTF-16 LE, but whatever encoded it assumed it was UTF-8 instead. Very wrong!

Comment: Does it just contain `\u0000`? Is this a complex structure? [aka Objects in Objects?]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It could be UTF-16. The original strings from the server are wchar_t*.

Comment: `\NULL` characters lead to invalid strings in many JS engines. Could you show us the code that generated this?

Comment: It's part of a large program so I'll try to put together a small test case.